# Is `git log <file>` better than O(all-commits-in-history)?

Tags: git

This question is just about understanding how Git works.

When I do `git log <file>`, does Git have to step through every parent commit and check which ones have changes to that file?

Or does it have some more efficient redundant/cached links from one change to another change for the same file/object?

Comment: Comparing already-calculated hash codes is about as efficient as you can get. Even with a million commits it's not an awful lot of work.

Comment: @jthill to be clear, are you saying that it doesn't even have to do a regular string-comparison on the `<file>` path, but can hash `<file>` once and then do hash comparisons because commits actually contain the *hash* of each path they changed?

Comment: That's the general idea. Say `git help -g` and start reading.

Comment: @mtraceur being pedantic: a commit does not _change_ a path. A commit contains a reference to a _snapshot_ (the tree) of your project at a certain time. Trees reference blobs by hash and every blob contains the _full_ content of a single file. [Git Book: 10.2 Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) will give you more insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the first one: Git will traverse the full history, looking at each tree of every commit whether the tree contains a blob mapped to the path specified by you. If the file has changed, the blob's hash code (stored in the tree) is different and the commit which references the tree will be included in the output.

Sometimes side branches of a merge can be skipped, if they are deemed "uninteresting", see [History simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) in the `git log` man page.

Since Git is Free Software, you can look at the source code yourself for all the nitty-gritty details: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/revision.c

Comment: A minor correction: each tree of every commit" omits some very effective optimizations, it walks just the path to the blob, and it can take an early out as soon as it sees an unchanged hash code, which means nothing in that directory has changed.

Comment: @jthill thanks, I forgot that trees are recursive and can contain blobs and other trees (and submodules). However, the log machinery still needs to look at least at the tree referenced by the commit, but not necessarily at every nested tree – so every commit has to be inspected

Answer (score 3):

`git log -- <file>` has to look at every commit starting at `HEAD`. Git does not store pre-computed information that would allow to shortcut to only commits that contain or change `<file>`.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it seems more comprehensive while basically including everything this does, but +1 to this one too!